# Prove that parallel projection creates a constant ratio $\vert \text{original}\vert:\vert\text{image}\vert$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the folloing parallel projection:

[image: Sketch of parallel projection]

According to the book $\displaystyle \frac {\vert AB\vert}{\vert A'B'\vert}=\frac{\vert BC\vert}{\vert B'C'\vert}=\frac{\vert CD\vert}{\vert C'D'\vert}=\ldots$

Now I'm usually not shy of a little Euclididean geometry, but I cannot for the life of me prove that this holds. Any suggestions?

Comment: Similar triangles?

Comment: I guessed that. But which ones?

Comment: The $IXX'$ where I is the intersection of 2 lines, and $X$ stands for $A, B, C, D$ or $E$. If $I$ does not exist then the ratio is simply 1.

Comment: ${AB\over A'B'}={\sin\alpha\over\sin\beta}$,

Comment: @user202729 As far as I can see, that only gives me that $\displaystyle \frac{\vert AI\vert}{\vert A'I\vert}=\frac{\vert BI\vert}{\vert B'I\vert}$, but not much more

Comment: Well, you can prove $\frac a b = \frac c d \Rightarrow \frac a b = \frac c d = \frac {a+c} {b+d}$ yourself, and then apply into that equality.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen that $\frac a b = \frac c d \Rightarrow \frac a b = \frac c d = \frac {a+c} {b+d}$. But that does do the trick. Could you convert this into an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of trig and construction. The ratios you gave from the book are cosine ratios of inclination angle $\alpha$ between two large sides of triangles with red hypotenuse parallels added from your sketch.

So all $\alpha$ s have the same value equal to these ratios.

[image: Parallels]

Comment: Just to use some different phrasing: Say $A''$ is the point where the red hypothenuse intersects $AA'$ and define $B''$, $C''$, etc analogously. Then $\triangle ABA''$ is similar to $\triangle BCB''$ is similar to ...(etc)

Comment: Correct. I left this as hint for further recognition of similarities in the series of right triangles. Also did not add many labels to avoid crowding  in your original diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel transform $A'B'$ s.t. $B=B'$, then you can use sine rule 
 $${AB\over A'B'}={\sin\alpha\over\sin\beta}.$$ $\alpha$ is the angle between $A'A$ and $A'B$, $\beta$ is the angle between $AA'$ and $AB$. Two angles are the same for others.

Comment: But you cannot assume $B=B'$ without loss of generality. So what if $B\neq B'$...?

Comment: Parallel transform $A'B'$ s.t. $B=B'$. i.e. just draw another  line through $B'$ that parallel $A'B'$ and intersect $AA'$ in point $A''$. Then you can see a triangle $ABA''$ and  $A'B'=A''B$. @gebruiker

Comment: @gebruiker English is not my first language, maybe some misrepresentation in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying now. It's essentially the same as what [Narasimham is doing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2455654/145141), right? +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2 lines intersecting at point  $X$ in the first quadrant, acute angle.

1)Choose any point, say, on the lower ray, label it $ B'.$

2) Choose any point on the upper ray, label it $B.$

We get a $\triangle AB'B.$

Draw a parallel line to $B'B$ intersecting at $XB'$ at $A',$  say, to the left of $B'$, I.e. $XA' \lt XB',$  and intersecting $XB$ at $A$.

$\triangle XA'A$ and $\triangle XB'B$ are similar.

1)$BB'/AA' = XB'/XA' = XA'/XA' + A'B'/XA' =$

$1+ A'B'/XA'$.

Likewise:

2) $BB'/AA' = 1 + AB/XA$.

Subtracting 2) from 1) yields:

$A'B'/XA' = AB/XA,$ or

$A'B'/AB= XA'/XA.$

To continue:

Draw a parallel to $B'B$ intersecting at $C'$ and $C$, proceed likewise.